# Using PySpark join on two dataframes. I have one unique_id and one non_unique_id column in separate DF. How to filter non-unique column by unique_id?

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark

There are two dataframes. The first one is named `products_purchased`, the second one is named `products_suggested`.

In the `products_purchased` alias(pp) table there is a `customer_id` (unique) column, an `item_id` column, and a `purchased` column (with the value of 1).

The `products_suggested` alias (ps) table has a `customer_id` (non-unique) and an `item_id` column. This table has more customer_id's than the product_product purchased table, as not all customers who are suggested items, purchase them.

I would like to join the two tables, retaining the `purchased` column for the places where `ps.customer_id` (non-unique) and an `ps.item_id` match `pp.customer_id` (unique) column, an `pp.item_id`. I would also like to keep any records where `pp.customer_id` (unique) match `ps.customer_id`(non-unique).

The idea is to have a table where only the records relate to the customers who went on to purchase an item. That item would be labeled with a 1 in the purchased column, their other suggested items would be labeled 0.

```
Product Suggested Table

 customer_id|item_id       |   
+----------+---------------+
|     16413|          51654|   
|     16413|          75950|
|     16413|        1366117|
|     78450|          56107|               
|     94038|          72358|               
|     94038|        1451889| 
|    113067|          75077|       
|     89578|          53279|
```

```
Product Purchased Table

 customer_id|item_id       |purchased 
+-----------+--------------+---------+
|      16413|         75950|        1|
|      78450|         56107|        1|
|      94038|         72358|        1|
```

```
Final Table

 customer_id|item_id       |purchased 
+-----------+--------------+---------+
|      16413|         51654|        0|
|      16413|         75950|        1|
|      16413|       1366117|        0|
|      78450|         56107|        1|       
|      94038|         72358|        1|     
|      94038|       1451889|        0|
```

I tried a left join on customer_id and item_suggested. I got what I expected, a table with all the suggested items regardless of their customer purchased, then the purchased status attached:

```
final = products_suggested.join(
  products_purchased,on =["customer_id",'item_id'], how= 'left')
```

```
Final Table

 customer_id|item_id       |purchased 
+-----------+--------------+---------+
|      16413|         51654|        0|
|      16413|         75950|        1|
|      16413|       1366117|        0|
|      78450|         56107|        1|       
|      94038|         72358|        1|     
|      94038|       1451889|        0|
|    113067|          75077|        0|
|     89578|          53279|        0|
```

I tried an inner join as well on just the customer_id. That made it so all my purchased columns were 1. I'm guessing thats because anywhere a customer_id matched the purchased version, it just placed the 1.

I also tried filtering after the left join `.where(pp['customer_id']==ps['customer_id])`, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: I'm thinking creating a list of the purchased clients and filtering by .isin(). I'm just not sure that's the best method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another dataframe that only had the customer_id from the product purchased. Then I joined the merged left join table I tried above, with an inner join. This filtered out the remaining non purchasing customers.

```
purchase_only_customers = left_join_table.join(purchase_table, on =["customer_id"], how= 'inner')
```